# Failed to launch test

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

I am trying to add Junit test cases to my project. here is my test case code

```
public class COMPUTEtest<A> {

    Dijkstra tester = new Dijkstra();

    @Test
    public void testAdd()
    {
        ArrayList<Vertex> metro= new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        Vertex A = new Vertex("Chennai",Lane.BLACK);
        Vertex B = new Vertex("Banglore",Lane.GREEN);
        Vertex C = new Vertex("Hyderabad",Lane.BLUE);
        Vertex D = new Vertex("Pune",Lane.RED);
        Vertex E = new Vertex("Hosur",Lane.BLACK);
        A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B, 1) , new Edge(C, 1), new Edge(D, 2)};
        B.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(D, 1) ,new Edge(E, 2),new Edge(A, 1)};
        C.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(D, 2),new Edge(A, 1) };
        D.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(E, 2) ,new Edge(A, 2),new Edge(B, 1)};
        E.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(D, 2),new Edge(B, 2) };
        List<Vertex> path=Dijkstra.getShortestPathTo(A, E);
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
    }
}
```

When I run the test,This is my error in Log cat

> 10-16 03:14:39.108: E/memtrack(1374): Couldn't load memtrack module
>   (No such file or directory) 10-16 03:14:39.108:
>   E/android.os.Debug(1374): failed to load memtrack module: -2

I am using Eclipse Juno, ADT 23.0 JUnit 4

Comment: Do you want to test a Java-only class, that does not depend on Android?

Comment: Yes I want to test a separate java class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace
`public class COMPUTEtest<A> {`
with
`public class COMPUTEtest extends TestCase {`

and import:
`import junit.framework.TestCase;`